# Android app + Image storage and retrieval

Tags: android, database, image, data-retrieval

I am designing a restaurant based app which has lots of images.

Please tell me:

1. How should I save images in the database i.e. in which format so that time of retrieval and display in the app is minimum? (Note: This database is a MySQL and located on an external server).
2. How should I retrieve them, i.e. which method to go for (JSON, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use remote database server connection from application directly it may lead to slow performance . Instead use  webservices as a intermediator between the database and your application. Your app should call a webservice which will internally query your database and return you the response . First response can be XML or JSON , but i would personally recommend you for the JSON as very fast from XML . Your first webservice response will return only the urls for images that you should download asynchronously so that UI thread is not hanged up .

Comment: Yes, I am using Php for webs ervices. As you said about 'URLs' that means I should save the references(URL) of the images in the database and not in BLOB format?

Comment: Yes , I mean to say exactly that and download it directly from app .

Comment: thanks a lot.. so I just re-iterate my understanding:: 1. Use web service. 2. Save URLs of images in the database. 3. Retrieve URLs and download images directly from app in a separate thread. 4. Use JSON as the method of retrieval.

Comment: If you got your answer then tick mark the above answer of mine.